# can't compile Qt qextserialport library

Tags: qt, compilation, executable, qextserialport

I'm trying to use qextserialport Library:

1. Download:
   `git clone https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/`
2. Open qextserialport.pro with Qt
3. Compile... (debug mode)

I got no errors, but window appears:

> Couldn't find Executable, please choose one.

Which one should I choose?

N.B.: I'm on MacOSX 10.6 using Qt 3.1.1

Comment: You could try reading the [installation instructions](https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/wiki/QextSerialPort_2_0_Preview).

Comment: Are you really using Qt **3.1.1** or is that a typo?

Comment: I'm using 3.1... is latest version of qextserialport uncompatible with Qt 3?

Comment: @user1824508 The latest version of **Qt** is **5.3.0** and the latest version of **Qt creator** is **3.1.1**. Are you really using Qt 3.1 ? It's quite obsolete.

Comment: A library has no executable to be run, its a library. You will have to create your own project (e.g. some serial communication software probably) which links to your compiled qextserialport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at least Qt 5.2 QSerialport is integrated and readily available in your code. I would recommend to switch to Qt 5.3 for new designs, if you are not already using it.

Comment: I fixed the problem Yesterday: couldn't install Qt 5.3 on OSX 10.6. Upgraded OsX 10.6 to 10.9 and installed Qt 5.3

Comment: Great to hear that it worked out for you.
Edit: Also nice that I now have a rep of 66(6) with the badges :-)